# Select multiple files on Google Drive App

Tags: applications, google-drive

Is it possible to select multiple files on the Google Drive App?

I tried every intuitive solution I could think of, perhaps it's possible on the Google Docs app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [Mar 6, 2015](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDrive/posts/TzDbxZJTEbr), you can trigger multiple files/folders selection on Google Drive app by long-pressing a file/folder, then ticking other files / long-pressing other folders.

After selecting them, you can:

- Star selected items
- Pin selected items
- Remove selected items, or
- Move to another folder (by selecting from the menu, or by dragging the "deck" to a folder)

Comment: It's still impossible when I need to select multiple files as attachments using gmail app and using "From google disk" option. I can select only single file. On the other side, when I use share option from Google drive app I can select multiple files but there is an option to add those files as physical copies (not links to files on google drive) which I don't want because of email attachments size limitation.

Comment: That's exactly as it works in other apps or on Android system in general. But the problem is, that you have to manually tick every single file what's useless when you need to select more files than a couple of them. It looks like there's no way to select a range of files.

Answer (score 1):

Simply first go gallery, select multiple files,  then select the share option, then select drive, all files will upload simultaneously.