# How can I select multiple images when uploading them to a website?

Tags: images, uploads

Does anyone know how to select multiple images when uploading them? I've attached a screenshot of where im trying to use a long press to select multiples but it's not working.

[image]

Update: I'm on a work website in an area where I can upload documents to a report. 
The image below is what I see when I click upload. I've also attached a second pic that shows what I see when I tap "Gallery". Uploading multiples works well on a PC but not on this tablet. There are a few guys in my company that it seems to work for but they aren't near me and this is something that IT would take forever to get to.

Specs:
Samsung Tab S 8.4 (SM-T700)
Android Version 4.4.2

[image]

Comment: this is in Gallery ? please edit your question and put more information about current Application, when you try it...anyway, in below i give you some information hope it can help you.

Comment: also : http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97668/select-multiple-files-on-google-drive-app/103577#103577

Answer (score 1):

**first Step :**

When you open the *Gallery*, you should see three soft keys at the **Button**, **Share**, **Delete** and More.

Click `Share` and you should get a *pop-up menu*. Select your method of sharing. Now, you should see little check boxes in the upper right hand corner of each pic.
 Check whichever pics you want to send. Deleting multiple pics works the same way, except obviously you'd select "Delete" instead of Share.

**Example :**

[image]

Also, this feature maybe added in latest Rom, you need to try it.this reply just for give you more information and acquaintance.

good day.