# How can I select a range of files on Google drive for Android?

Tags: android-10, files, google-drive

I know I can long press one file and then select other files by tapping each individual file to select multiple files.

But I need to select a range of files. So that I don't have to sit there and tap my screen like 100 times, I should be able to select a range of files. For example, select the first of 50 files in a folder, and then scroll down and select the 10th file and automatically select all 10 files.

Also, someone mentioned long pressing the first file and then, without lifting your finger, slide over any additional files. But this does not work on Google Drive.

How can I batch select a range of files without having to tap my screen 100 times to select 100 files (for example)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Select multiple files on Google Drive App](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/97668/44325). AFAIK, there's been no update regarding this on the official app since then. If I'm not mistaken, there's an answer somewhere else mentioning using a 3rd-party file manager app that can integrate with Google Drive and support range selection, but I can't find it currently... or I had a hallucination...

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if you read that question but I pretty clearly cover [that answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/103577/) in my question here (long press on one file and then tap additionally files individually, so 99 additional taps for 100 files).

Comment: No worry, I just linked the Q&A as a reference for everyone else.

Comment: Download [MiXplorer](https://xdaforums.com/t/app-2-2-mixplorer-v6-x-released-fully-featured-file-manager.1523691/), click on the **+** to add Drive and you can select a range by long pressing. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iczlg.png) @AndrewT

Comment: To be clear, select one file, and for example go to 10th file, long press on it to select all 10 files//You can delete, copy - paste to your phone etc

Comment: Drive for some reason takes a long to time to load in the file explorer and this may not suitable if you frequenting wish to do this. Other cloud services I use are pretty fast